# How can I upload a file even if the window is inactive?

Tags: python, selenium

My code to upload a file :

```
exe_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "\\uploadfile.exe"

subprocess.call(exe_path + " " + file_path_to_upload)
```

But the driver is getting closed if the window is not active. I need to upload a file using Selenium in Python even if the screen is inactive (due to displaying an error message dialogue for example).

Comment: this might have something useful for you... not sure... check it out... https://automatetheboringstuff.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("IdToYourButton")
element.click()
element.send_keys("fullPathToYourFile")
```